# How to fix " Path is required ,ValidationError " ,Mongoose ,node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I have searched everywhere for this problem. but I cant find the correct way to fix it. help me to what is the problem.

```
    const router = require("express").Router();
    let Reg = require("../models/Register");

    http://localhost:8070/Register/add

  router.route("/add").post((req,res)=>{

const name = req.body.Name;
const email = req.body.Email;
const number = Number(req.body.Number);
const password = req.body.Password;


const NewAdd = new Reg({
    name,
    email,
    number,
    password

})

NewAdd.save().then(()=>{
    res.json("Registration Added")
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err);
    res.json(err)
    console.log("reg err");
})



 })
```

and this is a module folder js

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');

 const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 const RegSchema = new Schema({

Name: {
    type: String,
    required: true

},
Email: {
    type: String,
    required: true

},
Password: {
    type: String,
    required: true

},
Number: {
    type: Number,
    required: true

}

    });

     const Register = mongoose.model("Register",RegSchema);

      module.exports = Register;
```

This is server .js

```
    const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser =require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
 require("dotenv").config();
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8070;

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());


const URL = process.env.MONGODB_URL;

mongoose.connect(URL,{
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopologyL: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
});

const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once("open", () =>{
    console.log("Mongodb connection success!");
})


const AddRouter = require("./routes/Registers.js");


app.use("/Register",AddRouter);



app.listen(PORT, () =>{
    console.log(`The port is : ${PORT}`);
})
```

error showing

> Name: ValidatorError: Path `Name` is required.
> at validate (C:\Users\Sliit\Desktop\Reg-Backend\Travel-management-system\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1270:13)
> at C:\Users\Sliit\Desktop\Reg-Backend\Travel-management-system\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1253:7
> at Array.forEach ()
> at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (C:\Users\Sliit\Desktop\Reg-Backend\Travel-management-system\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1198:14)
> at C:\Users\Sliit\Desktop\Reg-Backend\Travel-management-system\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2545:18
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
> properties: [Object],
> kind: 'required',
> path: 'Name',
> value: undefined,
> reason: undefined,
> [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
> }
> },
> _message: 'Register validation failed'
> }

I testing API from the postman and get this error

> "errors": {
> "Number": {
> "name": "ValidatorError",
> "message": "Path `Number` is required.",
> "properties": {
> "message": "Path `Number` is required.",
> "type": "required",
> "path": "Number"
> },
> "kind": "required",
> "path": "Number"
> },
> "Password": {
> "name": "ValidatorError",
> "message": "Path `Password` is required.",
> "properties": {
> "message": "Path `Password` is required.",
> "type": "required",
> "path": "Password"
> },
> "kind": "required",
> "path": "Password"
> },
> "Email": {
> "name": "ValidatorError",
> "message": "Path `Email` is required.",
> "properties": {
> "message": "Path `Email` is required.",
> "type": "required",
> "path": "Email"
> },
> "kind": "required",
> "path": "Email"
> },
> "Name": {
> "name": "ValidatorError",
> "message": "Path `Name` is required.",
> "properties": {
> "message": "Path `Name` is required.",
> "type": "required",
> "path": "Name"
> },
> "kind": "required",
> "path": "Name"
> }
> },
> "_message": "Register validation failed",
> "name": "ValidationError",
> "message": "Register validation failed: Number: Path `Number` is required., Password: Path `Password` is required., Email: Path `Email` is required., Name: Path `Name` is required."
> }

Answer (score 1):

Use the same case in "NewAdd" and in "RegSchema".

```js
const NewAdd = new Reg({
  name,
  email,
  number,
  password
})
```

and

```js
const RegSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  number: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I have changed my schema while my server is running. I just restart the server and error is gone. If you also changed your schema while your server is still running try to restart your server.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Follow up and need to check this all point

```
1. add app.use(express.json()) in app.js file
2. use req.body for storing a data in mongodb.
eg app.post('/student',(req,res)=>{
   const user= new Student({
       name:req.body.name,
       email:req.body.email,
number:req.body.number,
message:req.body.message
   })
user.save().then(()=>{
res.status(201).send(user)
}).catch((e)=>{
res.status(400).send(e)
})
```

3. select JSON option on dropdown of postman
   [image]